# get Stripe customer_id after successful order in Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, strip

We have a Stripe Gateway plugin on WooCommerce.
When order is complete I need to get customer_id from Stripe customer profile and send it to our third party api.
Is there a hook available in WooCommerce to do this task?
Whether Stripe returns back to WooCommerce with some data that I can access?

Comment: Maybe you can configure a webhook and Stripe and capture order data in your website. If you read the plugin [documentation](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/stripe/?_ga=2.202695057.162801758.1623749404-1133362913.1618812072) , it exists a hook called: wc_gateway_stripe_process_webhook_payment ($response, $order) – Called after a webhook payment process.

Comment: sorry still not clear how Stripe returns customer_id in response to WoCommerce